# C# Redirect to a new url when user scan QR CODE

Tags: c#, redirect, xamarin, xamarin.forms, qr-code

I'm using QRCODE.net library to generate QR Barcode and it's work fine. The thing is that I want that when the user scan the code with an **Xamarin App**, the web page **which has the qr-code** redirect to another url(Like WhatsApp web does). Do you have any idea to do that?

I was following this example already: http://tech.trailmax.info/2012/09/generate-qr-barcode-in-asp-net-mvc/

I have already searched a lot in Google and still haven't found any relevant information in this regard.

Comment: Is your app doing the QRCode read? Most QR readers handle urls being embedded and open the clients default web browser. What information are you currently embedding in the QR Code?

Comment: I've edited the question. @Mike

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need several pre-requirements

1. your app must be able to access a certain url embedded in your QR code after it scanned it.
2. you need a websocket connection between the user's browser and your page showing the QR Code, or you can keep something refreshing on that page, like an auto-refreshed iframe or an interval js script

then the solution flow will be

1. page shows the QR Code with an embedded url contains an unique key, meanwhile store the unique key on the server, tag the key as "not scanned", establishes the websocket or starts the interval refresh
2. app scans the QR, and sends a request to the embedded url
3. the embedded url recieves the request with the unique key, then find the key stored on server and tag it as "scanned"
4. if you use websocket, then detect the change of the key's status, push a message to client browser to redirect to wherever you want. if you use interval refresh, then when re-load, just pull the status of current key, if status is "scanned" then redirect

Comment: Thanks for answer my question. I realize Is better for me use Firebase to do that. Anyway thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a web application and if QR Code returns the url you can do

```
Response.Redirect(<barcode text>);
```

[HttpResponse.Redirect Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a8wa7sdt(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I don't understand ,can you explain a little more?

Comment: @MichaelAlexanderMontero if your application is an asp.net one, this is basically redirecting you to whatever the barcodes result is. so if the barcodes result is https://www.google.com.au then it will redirect you to that website

Comment: No no no, let me explain better. I have two applications, the web app where is the qr code, and an Android app which will scan the qr code. The the android app scan the app i want the web app redirect to another WEB page.@Werdna

Comment: @MichaelAlexanderMontero Then you should of put that in the question in the first place. We can't read your mind. You need a DB to which you put that QR code, some sort of user system and on access of the site retrievie the QR code and redirect.

Answer (score -1):

I use to used qrcodenet

static string url = "http://www.google.com";

static void GenerateQR()
{

```
QrEncoder qrEncoder = new QrEncoder(ErrorCorrectionLevel.M);
QrCode qrCode = qrEncoder.Encode(url);
for (int j = 0; j < qrCode.Matrix.Height; j++)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < qrCode.Matrix.Width; i++)
    {
        char charToPoint = qrCode.Matrix[i, j] ? '█' : ' ';
        Console.Write(charToPoint);
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

}